# Работа с сетью Android

Tags: android

Есть сервер где лежат  файлы pdf, задача чтобы приложение выводило список этих файлов в активити, при клике начиналась закачка.

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм действий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм действий:

1. Пишете API для сервера который будет отдавать список файлов с ссылкой, по которой их можно скачать.
2. Из приложения обращаетесь к этому API (например с помошью [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)) и отображаете полученный список в `ListView/RecyclerView`.
3. При клике на элемент списка начинаете закачку соответствующего файла (с помощью того же OkHttp или например, [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)).
4. ...
5. Профит